# Neo4j Cypher query for simple IP->FQDN bind dataset

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following incredible simple data-set, it contains IP->FQDN bind events with timestamps.

[image]

I have added this data to a neo4j graph.

[image]

I have been trying all day to write a query that returns "The ips that were bound to fqdn1 at timestamp 7"

I expect the result to be only ip2 because it was bound to fqdn1 at time 1 and then never bound to anything else before timestamp 7. I do not expect ip1 to be in the result set as it was bound to fqdn2 at time 2 and therefore it was not bound to fqdn1 at time 7.

I am getting nowhere with this and I expect its because I have not yet made the mental leap to the Cypher way of thinking.

Can someone please help me with this?

EDIT: The timestamp is stored as a property of the BOUND_TO relationships.

Comment: I think you need to make it more clear about your model. I think you are saying that you store a timestamp when a binding is made, but that you never clear that value i.e In your model if I were to look in isolation at ip1/ip2/fqdn1 I would not know if a binding were active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to guess where your timestamp is stored but I think what you probably want is this:

```
MATCH (f:FQDN{name:"fqdn1"})<-[:BOUND_TO{timestamp:2}]-(ip:IP)
RETURN ip
```

**Edit - In case you want ranges**

```
MATCH (f:FQDN{name:"fqdn1"})<-[bound:BOUND_TO]-(ip:IP)
WHERE bound.timestamp >= 1 AND bound.timestamp < 5
RETURN ip
ORDER BY bound.timestamp ASC
```

**Edit - After question updated**

I don't think that this is a good idea, and I would look at how your model could be adjusted to store the timeseries data in a more graph like way, but something like this (relatively untested):

<s>MATCH (f:FQDN { name:"fqdn1" })<-[b:BOUND_TO]-(ip:IP)
    WHERE b.timestamp <= 2
    WITH f, b, ip
    MATCH (other:FQDN)<-[ob:BOUND_TO]-(ip)
    WHERE other <> f AND ob.timestamp < b.timestamp AND ob.timestamp <= 2
    RETURN f, b, ip</s>

The above won't quite work, need to use the results as a filter:

```
MATCH (f:FQDN { name:"fqdn1" })<-[b:BOUND_TO]-(ip:IP)
WHERE b.timestamp <= 3
OPTIONAL MATCH (other:FQDN)<-[ob:BOUND_TO]-(ip)
WHERE other <> f AND ob.timestamp > b.timestamp AND ob.timestamp <= 3
WITH ip, b, COLLECT(ob) AS bindings
WHERE LENGTH(bindings)= 0
RETURN ip
```

**Aside - depending on the use case**

You *might* want to store just the active bound IPs as direct relationship to the FQDNs, and then add a (manually managed) list of historical bindings behind that single bound IP. This is because it is faster to traverse the list then to query by timestamps / order by timestamps.

Comment: This will not work as I want to store a relation for every ip->fqdn binding event (ip:IP)-[r:BOUND_TO {timestamp: t}]->(fqdn:FQDN).

I do not want to maintain an active list of bindings. The graph encodes the information I want, I just need to craft the correct cypher query to extract it.

Comment: @CathalCoffey What does the provided query not achieve?

Comment: JohnMark13 your query returns both ip1 and ip2 even though I explicitly stated in my question that I expect the answer to only return ip2 because ip1 was bound to fqdn2 at time 2. This constraint is why I have not been able to write the cypher query myself.

Comment: Downvote is a little harsh, but I'll live. The query is fine, your question must be missing something, i.e you must have a relationship (fqdn1)<-[:BOUND_TO{timestamp:2}]-(ip1) AND (fqdn1)<-[:BOUND_TO{timestamp:2}]-(ip2), can you check?

Comment: JohnMark perhaps you misunderstood my intent, I have now reworded the question.

Comment: JohnMark your updated answer looks perfect, I just modified the with clause to return only the largest timestamp per ip.

WITH ip, max(b.timestamp) as t, COLLECT(ob) AS bindings
WHERE LENGTH(bindings)= 0
RETURN ip, t